# How to use multiple states in one BlocListener with bloc_library?

Tags: flutter, bloc

For example I have the following pseudocode:

`if(state1.status==ok&&state2.status==ok) {do something}`

`MultiBlocListener` is not applicable here cause I can listen states separately only, I tried nested `BlocListener` and it haven't helped me because the outer `BlocListener` doesn't notify the inner about state changes. So in the inner one I can check state of outer only in the moment when inner state changes.

For now I solve this problem by using nested `BlocBuilder` and `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`. In this case the outer `BlocBuilder` rebuilds the inner one and I can check for multiple states changes correctly. But I'm not sure that this problem is usually solved this way.

Note: state1 from bloc1 and state2 from bloc2 or in other words multiple states from multiple blocs

Here is code I use now:

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'splash';
  static const logoUrl = 'assets/images/logo.svg';

  const SplashScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    void _navigateTo(String routeName) => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(routeName);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: BlocBuilder<SettingsBloc, SettingsState>(
        builder: (context, settingsState) {
          return BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
            builder: (context, authenticationState) {
              WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                if (authenticationState.status == AuthenticationStatus.UNAUTHENTICATED) {
                  Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => _navigateTo(LoginScreen.routeName));
                } else if (authenticationState.status == AuthenticationStatus.AUTHENTICATED) {
                  switch (settingsState.currentType) {
                    case FastAccessType.UNKNOWN:
                      break;
                    case FastAccessType.NONE:
                      Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => _navigateTo(HomeScreen.routeName));
                      break;
                    case FastAccessType.PIN:
                      Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => _navigateTo(PinCodeScreen.routeNameLogin));
                      break;
                    case FastAccessType.BIOMETRICS:
                      Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => _navigateTo(BiometricsScreen.routeName));
                      break;
                  }
                }
              });
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: mainGradient),
                child: Center(
                  child: WebsafeSvg.asset(SplashScreen.logoUrl),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As I see when I test it on my device navigation animation called twice and it doesn't look cleany.

Answer (score 0):

try condition

```
          BlocBuilder<BlocT, YourState>(
            bloc: bloc,
            condition: (c, s) => (s is ValidationState ),
```

Comment: I need to operate with state1 from bloc1 and state2 from bloc2. Your solution is previous and current state for single bloc

Comment: Can you explain more about your solution, maybe I didn't understand it.